# Delphi DBase III component

Tags: delphi, dbase

Hi could anyone recommend a free component that I can use to load dbase III tables into Delphi, preferably without using the BDE.

Something like TTable but for Dbase

thanks

colin

Comment: Since you haven't specified that you're using 64 bit XE2, I should point out that TTable + BDE have always natively supported dBase format, ever since Delphi 1.0, and still works in Delphi XE2 32 bit.

Comment: However, I do NOT suggest that you actually USE the BDE. I suggest you use TDBF, just as ain says.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[TDBF](http://tdbf.sourceforge.net/) should do what you want.

Comment: this is what you need. it is the best from what I've tried to work with dbf

Comment: Note that TDBF is released under the LGPL, which might be a bit too "free", depending on  what kind of software you want to use it for.

Comment: Well, if that's the case then you just use TDBF to do the sensible thing, which is to update your legacy application to use a modern database :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ADO (`TADOConnection` and `TADOTable` or `TADOQuery`) that come with Delphi, or use a third-party component.

If you decide on third-party, I suggest the [Advantage Database Server](http://www.sybase.com/delphi) (also known by `ADS` for brevity). It's local client version is free, and supports up to five connections. It's easily upscaleable to their full client-server engine, supports most SQL-92 functionality for SQL access (as well as having `TTable` type functionality), and comes with components compatible with all data-aware controls that connect via `TDataSource`. (The components include full Delphi source code.) You do have to distribute a couple of DLLs with your app, but they can easily be installed in the same folder as your app and don't require any system registration or registry entries.

They've been around since the old Clipper days, so they're not new kids. They were acquired a few years ago by Sybase, and have been releasing new versions every year, so they're not going anywhere anytime soon.

(I have no affiliation with Advantage or Sybase in any way; I've just used their product for years, and still do to support some legacy data and applications that can't be ported to a full SQL RDBMS for various reasons.)

Comment: Thanks. I'll edit my post. The link I posted still works, though. :)

Answer (score 0):

See the component VKDBF([web](http://vlad-karpov.narod.ru/Components.html#VK20DBF), [torry](http://www.torry.net/authorsmore.php?id=2689)) of Vladimir Karpov.